# React axios interceptor doesn't await rejected request

Tags: reactjs, authentication, axios, react-router, refresh-token

#### Description

There is a request in a protected route that should be processed only after verification have been processed. Access and refresh token are in cookies and are attached to all necessary requests.

#### Problem:

After access token is expired, backend returns `400`, should process block with `refreshing token` in axios interceptor, but first comes request from protected route, and then refresh

#### Screen

[image: requests]

#### Axios interceptor:

```
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { API } from '@/constants/api';
    import AuthService from '@/services/AuthService';
    
    export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
      baseURL: API.base,
      timeout: 15000,
      withCredentials: true,
    });
    
    axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
      async (config) => config,
      async (error) => Promise.reject(error),
    );
    
    axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
      async (response) => response,
      async (error) => {
        const config = error?.config;
    
        if (error?.response?.status === 400 && !config?.sent) {
          await AuthService.refreshTokenPair();
    
          return axiosInstance.request(config);
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
      },
    );
    export default axiosInstance;
```

#### Protected route:

```
      const ProtectedRoute = observer((): JSX.Element => {
      const { isAuth } = userStore;
      const handleUnauthorized = () => {
        userStore.isAuth = false;
      };
    
      useLayoutEffect(() => {
        const verify = async () => {
          const verifyDetails = await AuthService.verifyAccessToken();
    
          const details = await UserService.getUserDetails(verifyDetails?.id);
          if (!details) {
            handleUnauthorized();
            return;
          }
    
          userStore.user = details;
          userStore.isAuth = true;
        };
    
        verify();
      }, []);
    
      if (!isAuth) {
        return <Navigate to={ROUTES.home.path} replace />;
      }
    
      return <Outlet />;
    });
    export default memo(ProtectedRoute);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve by:

```
    if (error?.response?.status === 401 && config && !config.sent) {
      config.sent = true;
      try {
        await AuthService.refreshTokenPair();

        return await axiosInstance.request(config);
      } catch {
        return await Promise.reject(error);
      }
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
```

and protected:

```
      ...
      const verifyDetails = await AuthService.verifyAccessToken();
      if (!verifyDetails) {
        handleUnauthorized();
        return;
      }
      ...
      }, []); // UseEffect deps
      ...
```